# Where can mimeMap file extensions be defined besides web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, iis-express

Using IIS Express to run locally, I get this error:

`Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap' with unique key attribute 'fileExtension' set to '.less'`

The code in the web.config hasn't changed in a while - what else might have changed to cause me to get this error?

I can remove the mimeMap from web.config and the website runs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

MIME maps can be defined in IIS Express settings here:

`My Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config`

What changed? Something added a few new mime maps to IIS Express settings on my box (possibly Visual Studio 2015, but I can't verify.)

To resolve the issue and not affect coworkers, change web.config to:

```
<remove fileExtension=".less"/>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
```